# Network is blocking ports used by Azure AD?

Tags: cordova, azure, networking, azure-active-directory, adal

I have created an app that uses Azure Ad to authenticate my users.
Its a cordova app, that uses a "ADAL"-plugin to do the Authentication via OAuth2.

When my users try to log in, using their company network an error occurs (Everything is fine on cellular). 
They are shown the error: "err_address_unreachable".

I have tested the login and it works on different network and on cellular.
So I suppose my users company network are blocking a port or something that the app/login uses.

Any ideas what could is being blocked? So I can have the company check their settings, and maybe unblock something if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only port used is 443 for SSL/TLS communication with your site, login.microsoftonline.com and possibly some other Microsoft properties.

If your users are required to access the Internet through a proxy, then your app needs to support proxy communication.